# Проблема с использованием данных

Tags: c#, ооп, файлы, классы

Есть два файла, из которых требуется получить данные однако есть ещё два класса *BooksFile*,*ChitFile* которые используют эти два файла и есть две переменные в которые требуется записать информацию
[image: 1 Файл]
о читателях

[image: 2 Файл]
и о книге

[image: Вывод который я реализовал сам]
вывод который я сделал сам, однако информации о читателе и книги нет.
Вопрос, как вывести информацию из других классов
Допустим чтобы было в консоли
Книга : Алиса В Зазеркалье
Читатель : Кунакбаев Артем Равилевич Дзержинского 59 кв. 6 9227169197
Дата взятия книги: 01/12/2022 10:00:00 AM,
Ожидаемая дата возврата: 16/12/2022 10:00:00 AM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Курсовая_негра
{
    internal class Vidannie_knigi
    {
        int chit_id;
        int book_id;
        int rating;
        string date_pick;
        string date_waiting;
        Random r = new Random();
        BooksFile books = new BooksFile();
        ChitFile chitFile = new ChitFile();
        
        public string Date_pick { get { return date_pick; } }
        public string Date_waiting { get { return date_waiting; } }
        DateTime Date_pic = new DateTime(2022, 12, 1, 10, 00, 00);
        public void PrintAllVidbooks()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Книга: {0}, \nЧитатель: {1}, \nДата взятия книги: {2},\nОжидаемая дата возврата: {3}",chit_id,book_id, Date_pic,Date_pic.AddDays(+15));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Переменные в которые требуется записать chit_id, book_id

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Асу -> **Курсовая негра**.

Comment: В приведенном фрагменте кода нет информации о том, как заполняются экземпляры классов `BooksFile`  и `ChitFile`.  А Вы спрашиваете про **вывод данных**, хотя вначале нужно разобраться, как **заполнить данные** в экземплярах этих классов (видимо считать из приведенных Вами файлов).